# Limitations to FeaturePlot

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, training-data

I have been working on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/anashamoutni/students-employability-dataset) dataset. I am using this dataset to try out machine learning, and if the class could be determined by the other predictors.

I wanted to plot boxplots and density plots using the `featurePlot` function (from the `caret` package) to plot the factors against the class.

I decided to run the code below, and it is showing `NULL`.

Are there any limitations to using the function? Maybe 9x1 plots are too many?
Or is my code entered wrong?

```r
dataset <- Student_Employability_Datasets

#creating a reproducible dataset
dataset_sub <- dput(dataset[1:20,])
dataset_struct <- structure(
  list(
    `Name of Student` = c(
      "Student 1", "Student 2", "Student 3", "Student 4", "Student 5",
      "Student 6", "Student 7", "Student 8", "Student 9", "Student 10",
      "Student 11", "Student 12", "Student 13", "Student 14", "Student 15",
      "Student 16", "Student 17", "Student 18", "Student 19", "Student 20"
    ),
    `General Appearance` = c(4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 4, 4),
    `Speaking Manner` = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3),
    `Physical Condition` = c(4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 5, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3),
    `Mental Alertness` = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 4),
    `Self-Confidence` = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5),
    `Presenting Ideas` = c(5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4),
    `Communication Skills` = c(5, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3),
    `Student Performance Rating` = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5),
    Class = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -20L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
dataset <- dataset_struct

# changing some values to numerics
dataset <- dataset %>% mutate_at(c('GENERAL APPEARANCE', 'MANNER OF SPEAKING', 'PHYSICAL CONDITION', 'MENTAL ALERTNESS', 'SELF-CONFIDENCE', 'ABILITY TO PRESENT IDEAS', 'COMMUNICATION SKILLS', 'Student Performance Rating'), as.numeric)
sapply(dataset, class)

# changing the names of the column titles
names(dataset)[10] <- "Class"

# changing the class column to 0's and 1's
dataset$Class <- ifelse(dataset$Class == "Employable", 1, 0)

# creating a list of 80% of the rows in the original dataset for training
validation_index2 <- createDataPartition(dataset$Class, p=0.8, list = FALSE)

# selecting the 20% of the data for validation 
validation <- dataset[-validation_index2, ]

# using the remaining 80% of the data to train and test the model
dataset <- dataset[validation_index2, ]

# spliting input and output
x <- dataset[, 1:9]
y <- dataset[, 10]

#box and whisker plots for each attribute(ERROR)
featurePlot(x=x, y=y, plot = "box")

#density plots for each attribute by class value (ERROR)
scales <- list(x=list(relation="free"), y=list(relation="free"))
featurePlot(x=x , y=y, plot="density", scales = scales)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten, I just added it to the post. Thanks!